# Configure Nutch to only index specific filetypes in Solr

Tags: solr, nutch

I am looking for a way to configure Nutch to crawl the web, but only index certain types of files (XML to be specific) into Solr.  I'm pretty sure a custom plugin would do the job, probably based on the index-more code, but I'd rather not do that unless I have to.  I'm also sure I could suck everything into Solr then delete unwanted content with Solr's API, but this is a bit hacky.  Is there a way to configure Nutch to only index certain filetypes in Solr?

Answer (score 0):

In nutch you can define filters for urls. What about filtering by the name of the fileextension?

Answer (score 0):

You can filter the file type according to the extension.
You can specify the extensions you want to include or exclude in [regex-urlfilter.txt](http://svn.apache.org/viewvc/nutch/trunk/conf/regex-urlfilter.txt.template?view=markup)

e.g. for exclusion (-) :-

> #skip image and other suffixes we can't yet parse 29 # for a more extensive coverage use the urlfilter-suffix plugin
>   -.(gif|GIF|jpg|JPG|png|PNG|ico|ICO|css|CSS|sit|SIT|eps|EPS|wmf|WMF|zip|ZIP|ppt|PPT|mpg|MPG|xls|XLS|gz|GZ|rpm|RPM|tgz|TGZ|mov|MOV|exe|EXE|jpeg|JPEG|bmp|BMP|js|JS)$

with + you can just specify the inclusion list.

Comment: I only want to _index_ XML data; I would still like to crawl most of everything.  If I exclude everything but XML using regex-urlfilter, Nutch will only crawl XML documents.

Comment: So you want to change the behaviour of the indexer not the crawler.